# WebSocket is closed before the connection is established in Android 4.2

Tags: android, webview, socket.io

My `WebView` app has file download link with `download` attribute in anchor tag,

```
<a href="path/to/the/file" download>
```

I am using `socket.io` in my `WebView`. In Android 4.4.2, I am able to download the file without any `socket.io` interruption but in Android 4.2 webview, I have got below error

Error:

```
E/Web Console﹕ WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.:0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accidentally I changed `socket.io` version. After reverting to older version it started working.